# Native-starter-kit won't run properly

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm talking about this starter kit [here](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit)

What I have done:

1. Clone the repo to a local folder
2. cd into the folder, run `npm install`
3. Run `react-native link`
4. Run `react-native run-android`
5. Run `react-native run-android` again

What I got:

Error from React Packager

```
Looking for JS files in
   D:\Projects\ReactNative\native-starter-kit

Loading dependency graph...
React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
Bundling `index.android.js`  100.0% (974/974), done.
 ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Projects\ReactNative\native-starter-kit\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml'
{"errno":-4048,"code":"EPERM","syscall":"lstat","path":"D:\\Projects\\ReactNative\\native-starter-kit\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml"}
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Projects\ReactNative\native-starter-kit\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml'
    at Error (native)

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
for common problems and solutions.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I can't get the sample project deployed properly on my device. Notice that I run `react-native run-android` twice. 
The first time, the bundling finished, but my device only show white background with nothing whatsoever. Then I try to run it again.
The second, the react packager got an error.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Change directory to Android folder of your project:

```
cd /path/to/project/android
gradlew clean
react-native run-android again.
```